# Angular - patchValue FormControl

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have the formGroup bellow that i call in the method saveConvention, i want to get the group contract and edit the formControl conventionId in the createConvention service, i tried with the method mentioned bellow but when i try to display, conventionId is always null

```
  this.conventionForm = this.fb.group({
        shortname: fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        fullname: fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        contract: this.fb.group({
            conventionId: fb.control(null),
            signatureProvides: fb.control(null, Validators.required)
        })
    });


public saveConvention(data: FormGroup): void {
    let currentData: FormGroup = data;

    let formControlContract: AbstractControl = currentData.get('contract');

    data.removeControl('contract');
    this.conventionService.createConvention(data.value)
        .catch(err => {})
        .subscribe(res => formControlContract.patchValue({ conventionId: res.id }) );

   console.log(formControlContract.value);

   this.contractBenefitPartnerService.createContract(formControlContract.value)
         .catch(err => {}).subscribe(res => {});            
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use `updateValueAndValidity` after using patchValue for it to take effect.

```
this.conventionService.createConvention(data.value)
    .catch(err => {})
    .subscribe(res => {
       formControlContract.patchValue({ conventionId: res.id }) 
       formControlContract.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

> formControlContract.patchValue({ **contract:** {conventionId: res.id }})